# Why not Change Row background color based on cell value DataTable in jquery(java spring)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am trying to create a data table in my jsp page. There is call to controller and  return a response json. But here iam change color of datatable row based on cell value. But didnt work.

data table.

```
        oTable = $("#dataTable").dataTable({
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "${baseURL}/ReviewAlert/GetReviewAlert",
        "bProcessing" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "iDisplayLength": 15,
        "aLengthMenu": [[15, 20, 30, 50], [15, 20, 30, 50]],
        "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
                         if ( data[3]-currDate<0) {        
                           $(row).addClass('red');
                            }
                          } , 

        "aoColumns" : [ {
            "mDataProp" : "serialNumber",
            "bSearchable" : false,
            "bVisible" : false
        },{
            "mDataProp" : "aNumber"
        },{
            "mDataProp" : "aName"            
        }, {
            "mDataProp" : "reviewDate"   
        },{
            "mDataProp" : "reviewTitle"             
        },{
            "mData" : null,
            "sTitle": "Action",
            "bSearchable": false,
            "bSortable": false, 
            "sClass" : "alignCenter",
            "fnRender": function(obj) {
                var action="<input id='btnRvwView' type='button' title='View/Edit' class='button_view'></input>";

                return action;
            }
        }]
    });
```

and my css.

```
.red {background-color: red !important;}
```

Comment: can you put console.log() inside if condition whether it is coming there or not.

Comment: No. Code inside the function is not executing.

Comment: Your  "if ( data[3]-currDate<0)" condition is not getting executed? is there any error in browser console ??

Comment: "*But didnt work.*" - what, precisely, didn't work? In what way did it not work? What should have happened, and what actually happened? What errors, if any, are reported in your browser's console? What's the relevant -
 "*[mcve]*" - code to allow us to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS rule to override DataTables cell styles.

```
.red td { background-color: red !important; }
```